# filling pivot column fields that are null with values for the same time period for a view

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is a sample of the table to start with;

```
Identifier    Time    Type Value Etc    
D1      1/1/2015 0:00   A   3     10       
D1      1/1/2015 0:00   B   1     20       
D1      1/1/2015 0:00   C   2     30       
D1      1/1/2015 1:00   A   3     10       
D1      1/1/2015 1:00   B   0     20       
D1      1/1/2015 1:00   C   2     30       
D1      1/1/2015 2:00   A   3     10       
D1      1/1/2015 2:00   B   1     20       
D1      1/1/2015 2:00   C   2     30       
D2      1/1/2015 0:00   A   3     10       
D2      1/1/2015 0:00   B   0     20       
D2      1/1/2015 0:00   C   2     30       
D2      1/1/2015 1:00   A   3     10       
D2      1/1/2015 1:00   B   1     20       
D2      1/1/2015 1:00   C   2     30       
D2      1/1/2015 2:00   A   3     10       
D2      1/1/2015 2:00   B   0     20      
D2      1/1/2015 2:00   C   2     30
```

I have multiple fields for "Type" and "Etc" which represents multiple columns so I think I need something dynamic. What I need to do is for certain fields in "Type" I need to pivot it to a column(s). Here is what I have when I do it for "Type" = "B";

```
Identifier    Time    Type Value Etc    Type_B
D1      1/1/2015 0:00   A   3     10       NULL
D1      1/1/2015 0:00   B   1     20       1
D1      1/1/2015 0:00   C   2     30       NULL
D1      1/1/2015 1:00   A   3     10       NULL
D1      1/1/2015 1:00   B   0     20       0
D1      1/1/2015 1:00   C   2     30       NULL
D1      1/1/2015 2:00   A   3     10       NULL
D1      1/1/2015 2:00   B   1     20       1
D1      1/1/2015 2:00   C   2     30       NULL
D2      1/1/2015 0:00   A   3     10       NULL
D2      1/1/2015 0:00   B   0     20       0
D2      1/1/2015 0:00   C   2     30       NULL
D2      1/1/2015 1:00   A   3     10       NULL
D2      1/1/2015 1:00   B   1     20       1
D2      1/1/2015 1:00   C   2     30       NULL
D2      1/1/2015 2:00   A   3     10       NULL
D2      1/1/2015 2:00   B   0     20       0
D2      1/1/2015 2:00   C   2     30       NULL
```

Then I need to fill in the NULL's for the appropriate identifier and time for the other "Type" fields with the value of the pivot like this;

```
Identifier    Time    Type Value Etc    Type_B
D1      1/1/2015 0:00   A   3     10       1
D1      1/1/2015 0:00   B   1     20       1
D1      1/1/2015 0:00   C   2     30       1
D1      1/1/2015 1:00   A   3     10       0
D1      1/1/2015 1:00   B   0     20       0
D1      1/1/2015 1:00   C   2     30       0
D1      1/1/2015 2:00   A   3     10       1
D1      1/1/2015 2:00   B   1     20       1
D1      1/1/2015 2:00   C   2     30       1
D2      1/1/2015 0:00   A   3     10       0
D2      1/1/2015 0:00   B   0     20       0
D2      1/1/2015 0:00   C   2     30       0
D2      1/1/2015 1:00   A   3     10       1
D2      1/1/2015 1:00   B   1     20       1
D2      1/1/2015 1:00   C   2     30       1
D2      1/1/2015 2:00   A   3     10       0
D2      1/1/2015 2:00   B   0     20       0
D2      1/1/2015 2:00   C   2     30       0
```

I need this to set up a view of this data. Any help would be appreciated.

Rich

Comment: Lots of ways you could do it.   You could use your existing query as a CTE, and JOIN it back to wherever you get the data to fill in the NULLs.

Comment: I have no access to original table to add it back in. I can create views so that's why I need help. I pivot the data using MAX() and Case in the query used for the middle sample but I can't figure out how to setup the view and populate the NULL fields in the pivoted column.

Comment: It's not clear from your post how you are getting the Type_B column in the first place, and why some rows are NULL and others are not.

Comment: Pivot using MAX(CASE WHEN TYPE="B" THEN VALUE END) AS TYPE_B. The other fields are NULL because TYPE equals "A" and "C". However since all rows are associated with the same identifier and time I need to fill in the NULL's with the same value as TYPE "B". The other issue is that in the real table I can have hundreds of different TYPE's.